# Creating a session cookie inside a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Tomcat, servlets and Spring Web. I'm coming from a PHP background so I'm a little disoriented to say the least. I want a controller to create a session cookie for me.

I've been told that I can get the session like this in a standard servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  // Somewhere inside the method...
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

  // Set a cookie
      session.setAttribute("hello", "world");

  // More stuff...
}
```

How does this translate into the Spring Web MVC way of doing things? Can I create session cookies inside a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java Servlets (and Spring MVC in particular) you don't interact with session cookie directly, actually properly written servlet based application should work without cookies enabled, automatically falling back to URL based session id.

The way you provided is correct, although Spring is giving you much better (higher level) approaches like [session-scoped](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other) beans. This way you never interact with the session itself.

Comment: You linked to the 2.5.x documentation. Did you mean http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other?

Comment: Shouldn't matter (the first one I found on Google), but I fixed the link to point to 3.0, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing in your example have nothing to do with cookies.
session.setAttribute("key", valueObject);
Sets a java-object in the session. The session is kept at the server. The sessionid is the only thing communicated back to the client. It can be a cookie or it can be in the URL. The attributes in the session is not serialized to strings.

Cookies on the other hand are strings that are sent back to the client. It is the clients responsibility to store their cookies (and some people turn them off) and return them to the server.

Setting a cookie value from a complex object-graph will require serialization and deserialization. A session attribute will not.

If you want to read a cookie, use this:

```
@CookieValue("key") String cookie
```

In the controller parameter list. The cookie variable will be populated with the value from the cookie named "key".

To set a cookie, call:

```
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Thank you! I personally think this was the most useful and correct answer in this thread/question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to the HttpSession object by including it as a parameter in your controller's method(s):

```
public String get(Long id, HttpSession session) {

}
```

Spring will inject the current HttpSession object for you, and from there you can set attributes (like you did in your question).