# Spring : How to use session in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I have a login form and I want to display Name of user who logined .I want to use session in Spring MVC, but it's not work

This is UsersController

```
@PostMapping("/room/saveRegister")
public String saveRegister(@Valid Users users, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    usersService.save(users);
    redirect.addFlashAttribute("success", "Saved user successfully!");
    return "redirect:/room";
}

@GetMapping("/room/login")
public String login(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", new Users());
    return "login";
}
@PostMapping("/room/loginRoom")
public String login(@ModelAttribute("users") Users user, ModelMap modelMap, RedirectAttributes redirect,HttpSession session) {
if(usersService.findByEmailAndPass(user.getEmail(),user.getPass()) != null) {
    session.setAttribute("name",user.getName());
    return "redirect:/room";

}else {
modelMap.put("error", "Email or Password is not correct. Pleased Try Again");

return "login" ;
}
}
```

And in file .html,I add

```
    <li  ><a href="account.html"><span th:text ="${session.name}"></span></a></li>
```

But when I login successful . Name of User is not display . Session is not work. I don't know why

Comment: Someone pleased help me

Comment: You aren't using the user retrieved from the database.

Comment: Please refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847618/creating-a-session-cookie-inside-a-controller

Comment: @M.Deinum I login by account in database , everything about login is done but I want to display name of users by session .. but it's not work

Comment: Again, you aren't using the user retrieved from the database. I assume the user only enters his username/password. So the passed in user doesn't contain anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `${sessionScope.name}` instead of `${session.name}`

More details can be found at **[Examples of EL Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)**

Comment: @datnguyen94 you need to check if the username is null when using `session.setAttribute`

Comment: When I use ${sessionScope.name} .. It will error EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

[Using Http Session With Spring Based Web Applications](https://dzone.com/articles/using-http-session-spring)